# How can I fix user input issue in VS Code on M1 Macbook?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, user-input, apple-m1

I am having trouble getting VS Code to let me take user input in the terminal on my m1 macbook. I am using gcc and have code runner installed with the run in terminal setting checked. I am running the program using the button on top right of VS Code. My program will print to the terminal, but not take user code and give me the message shown in the screenshot. I also get the same results using clang. [Output after running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Ce0.png)

I have checked all settings I know to check and checked my gcc version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Code Runner extension? If so, you need to put `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). The default value of that setting is `false`, which means Code Runner will show the program's output. The Output Panel can't take user input. Related setting definition: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/package.json.